# output data from HTML/database to MS word?

Tags: html, database, jsp

I'm just wondering if it is possible to output data from a webpage to MS word? I'm trying to have a link on my webpage(HTML/JSP code), when clicked this automatically opens the MS word application and builds a report inside Word based on information stored in my database(MS Access). So the report can be easily edited before printed. This database is linked to my HTML/JSP coded website. Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Just a note that .rtf files should be easier to generate and are still readable by MS Word.

Comment: So I could load a RTF file from a link on my HTML or JSP webpage. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: So basically, depending on how the database is set up, you could write the result of the SQL query or whatever data you want to an .rtf file that will be saved to the server and then link to that file for download. If you need the space, you could have it deleted later on.

Comment: @RDrazard, the database is set up using SQL statements. I'm going to try the .rtf file now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the SQL statements in my webpages dont seem to generate properly in the .rtf file. The statement e.g **SELECT * from Company;**, appears instead.

Comment: Are you particularly outputting the results of the query and not just the query itself?

Comment: the query itself is just printing out, but I need the statement to output the results from the database.